# Http Post request returns HTML instead of Csv data

Tags: python, node.js, express, google-apps-script

I am trying to fetch a `csv` off of an aspx website. There is no direct link to the `csv`, it is server generated when posting the form.

The following works correctly in Google App Script using UrlFetchApp:
It returns raw `.csv` data.

```
  ..// other code omitted for brevity

  var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://www.mycompanyurl.com/summary.aspx", {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {"Cookie": myCookieData},
    "payload": {
      '_ctl0:contact:isActive': '1',
      '__VIEWSTATE': myViewstateData,
      '__EVENTTARGET': '_ctl0:Main:ButtonExport',
      '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
      '__LASTFOCUS': '',
      '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': '',
      '__PREVIOUSPAGE': ''
    }
});

Logger.log(page); // <---- prints the csv file content
```

I've tried to emulate this in python requests library.

```
..// other code omitted for brevity
..// cookies are in the session 's'

page = s.post(
  'https://www.mycompanyurl.com/summary.aspx', 
  data={
    '_ctl0:contact:isActive': '1',
    '__VIEWSTATE': myViewstateData,
    '__EVENTTARGET': '_ctl0:Main:ButtonExport',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
    '__LASTFOCUS': '',
    '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': '',
    '__PREVIOUSPAGE': ''
  }
);

print(page) // <---- prints the html content of the page
```

I have omitted 2 other libraries I tried that ended in the same result. axios (node.js) and request (node.js)

Why does the request work on Google Script but not in other, more popular libraries.

Probably something simple I am missing, but after many hours of trying different header configurations and multiple libraries, I am at a loss.

Comment: I hack-solved this (not a real solution) by payloading all empty strings except for _eventtarget, and it works in both libs I need it to work for.

Answer (score 0):

The first difference I can see between the two code snippets is that you are not passing your cookies into the Python version.

It would be beneficial if you had a look at the HTML you got in response. Perhaps there's some error message (like: *Please log in*).

Try [adding your cookies to the request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies) and see if that helps.

Comment: I forgot to mention about the cookies are passed in the session 's' in the python example. I omitted the login code also, the page can't even be accessed without being logged in. It's definitely working, because I can navigate the logged in portion of the site using get and post requests and tracking the viewstate